# How to show a circle and a elipse is homomorphic in $R^{2}$?

Tags: metric-spaces

The question is to show that a circle and a elipse are homomorphic in $R^{2}$.

I have two questions 1) should I consider only the boundary points of circles and elipse?

2) what is the suitable function for this?.

Comment: Since you tagged "metric-spaces" did you mean "homeomorphic" instead? And by $R^2$ did you mean the real plane $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Answer (score 0):

1. Usually, yes, we mean only the contour by a 'circle' or 'ellipse'. For the solid circle, we rather use 'disk'. But here it doesn't matter.
2. In a suitable coordinate system, it's $(x,y)\mapsto (ax, by)$ for some $a,b>0$.